# The best method for Authorization Redirection

Tags: angular, typescript, redirect, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm trying to implement an authorization feature for an Angular application. Here are my steps.

1. Generate state and code in the FE.
2. Once the login button is clicked, redirect the application to /auth with some query parameters. (response type, redirect URI, state and code)

Once I redirect the application, another GET method is called, and I need to get the state and code parameters of the last URL and use those to get access and refresh tokens. I have implemented the above scenario in the following way.

componet.ts

```
loginHandler(): void {
    const CodeChallenge = this.codeGenService.getRandonNumber(43);
    const State = this.codeGenService.getRandonNumber(20);

    this.authService.redirect(State, CodeChallenge);
}

listenToRouteParameters(): void {
    this.routeSub = this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => {
      const State = params.get('state');
      const Code = params.get('code');
      const CodeVerifier = this.cookieService.getCookieValue(State);
      if (State && Code && CodeVerifier) {
        this.cookieService.removeCookie();
        this.initiateTokenExchange(Code, CodeVerifier);
      } else {
        const REFRESH_TOKEN = this.localStorageService.getItem('refresh_token');
        if (REFRESH_TOKEN) {
          this.refreshTokens(REFRESH_TOKEN);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

service.ts

```
redirect(state: string, codeChallenge: string): void {
    window.location.href= environment.baseURL + '/authorize?response_type=' + AuthConfig.responseType + '&redirect_uri=' + AuthConfig.redirectURI + '&state=' + state + '&code_challenge=' + codeChallenge;
  }
```

I have used the listenToRouteParameters function to listen for state and code query parameters in the same component.ts, and then call the service to get access and refresh tokens.

Instead of using redirection as above, I can call the HTTP GET method for redirection as below, but getting query parameters after that is a challenge. As you can see, If I get code as the first query parameter in the URL, the below logic does not work.

```
this.authService.authorize(this.State, this.CodeChallenge).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        // get state and code from URL
        const URL = data.url;
        const State = URL.split('state=').pop().split('&')[0];
        const Code = URL.split('code=').pop().split(';')[0];

        const CodeVerifier = this.cookieService.getCookieValue(State);
        this.initiateTokenExchange(Code, CodeVerifier);
      }
    )
```

**I would like to know what is the correct approach for authorization redirection or are there any other method to achieve the same?**

Edit:
The /auth has a location property in its response and that's the additional GET method that runs automatically. This GET method has two query parameters which I require to obtain access and refresh token.

Comment: I recently wrote a library that's very hands-off, small and not framework specific: https://github.com/badgateway/oauth2-client . Your code contains *many* bugs that make it incompatible with OAuth2.. I hope this helps, but if not.. take a look at the source because you need to do most of the same things.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ok, reworking an answer based off your comments. I'll leave the original full spam below.

Ok, as Evert says, we're simulating an oauth type round trip, fair enough.

I'm assuming from whatever course your on you understand approximately what it's supposed to be doing?

Essentially you pop over to some login page (usually as a popup window or something), which is <insert auth provider, e.g. google, facebook, etc>, and not actually within your app.

You sign in on that page and, when successful, it will redirect to whatever url you've told it to, attaching whatever tokens or whatnot it will as the query params of that url.

On that page *in your app* that it's returned the user to, you read the query params and do your thing, whatever that may be, but essentially the 3rd party service has said that yep, that's you, be on your way.

So, I'm going to assume that your environment/server/app is set up appropriately already such that there's no issue with deep linking within your app (that's a whole other topic) and when you are returned to your desired redirect url after logging in, you have access to the query params.

Already shown, I guess, as it works other than your attempts at parsing the url.

I suggest doing some more targeted Googling, as you should find a variety of [articles](https://readerstacks.com/how-to-get-query-string-params-in-angular-12/) around reading the query params from the current url.

The linked article will probably do the job - one of its first comments as it makes use of the `ActivatedRoute` is that it's good enough for a one-time read (i.e. after a redirect) but not if you expect the url to change (you don't), so the first example would likely do the job for you.

```
export class HelloworldComponent {
  constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    //this will only give first time and will not subscribe if there is change in url
    let id=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("id"));
    //or 
   //it will subscribe the url changes and will update the component accordingly
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(data=>{
       alert(data.get("id"));
    });
   }
}
```

So just a couple of usages:

```
const state = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("state"));
const code = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("code"));
```

Have a bash at that.

---

Original answer:

So many questions. Where to start?

Routing. Let's start there. It looks and sounds suspiciously like you're routing to just another page in your app, but you're using `window.location` to do it.

When this is used, the browser page is literally refreshed to that location, and unless you have something set up appropriately, you'll lose any knowledge of the initially loaded URL when the Angular app starts up and takes over routing.

Routing within Angular should be done via the `Router`.

When you're routing appropriately, [a world of possibilities](https://www.turing.com/kb/9-ways-to-pass-through-angular-routerstate) open up to you.

At its most basic, you can do very much as you've got there:

```
constructor(private readonly router: Router) { }

private navigateSomewhere(): void {
    const url = '/authorize?response_type=' + AuthConfig.responseType 
        + '&redirect_uri=' + AuthConfig.redirectURI 
        + '&state=' + state 
        + '&code_challenge=' + codeChallenge;

    this.router.navigate([url]);
}
```

However, you can also send state (data) through route changes with the router too...

```
this.router.navigate(['/authorise'], {state: {redirectUrl: '...', state: '...', codeChallenge: '...'});
```

and then pull it out on the other side once the redirection has happened and your component loads:

```
constructor() {
    console.log('state: ', history.state);
}
```

Note that it's done in the constructor, not on `ngOnInit` - I vaguely recall there might be some reason for that (by maybe not, maybe it's just the example I'm looking at, but I suspect there is as all 4 usages we have in this project are all done in there).

---

Next questions include: why are you routing somewhere else to do a login request?

Is there a particular reason you're routing to a whole other page to do a basic login request?

I would expect a login redirect to happen *after* logging in. A basic login page consists of two text boxes and a button that sends a request (usually post, but dealers choice I guess), and receives a response back.

Ideally success, but not always. If success, redirect the user to whatever 'home' page is relevant, or if not, throw up a message saying login failed.

You seem to be redirecting them to another page, introducing the complexity of passing data between the routes, so that this other page can send of that request before, presumably, redirecting the user again on successful or failed login.

---

URL parsing next.

Angular has a [URL serializer](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer).

Look into it's usage or some other form of URL parser so that you can quickly and accurately get the query params from a URL string rather than doing a botch job yourself.

Then you can use your second more direct method rather than going via eleventeen different routes.

Comment: This is actually an assignment, and the task tells that the app should redirect to <auth-server>/authorize first to get some properties which requires for access token generation API. Once I redirect, another GET request starts automatically and I need the query parameters of that API to get access tokens. Your explanation makes sense. SPA should not programmatically refresh the application. I am yet to find a solution to the problem I have mentioned in the latter part of the question, which is getting query parameters from the API URL.

Comment: Your comments make sense if this were a random Angular page, but given that this is supposed to be OAuth2, it's not OAuth2 unless there's real redirect.